# How do I make keras predict something other than a one-hot matrix?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have a dictionary of 122 unique values. I'm feeding the program over 45,000 records with 33 data points to refer to when making a prediction about what the output should be. What I've noticed is that it's only predicting `[[1.]...]`. I need it to predict 1's 2's 3's ... up until 122. All are floats as well, so I don't know if that matters.

Here is my code-

```
Y = faults['FAILMODE']
del faults['FAILMODE']
X = faults

len(Y.FAILMODE.unique())
122
```

This is how I intend on associating the output with the actual string value (like 'Exhaust')

```
classes = {}
n = 1.
for u in Y:
    if u not in classes:
        classes[n] = u
        n += 1.
    else:
        n += 1.
```

I use this to turn all data into unique floats in the DataFrame.

```
for col in X:
    values = pd.Series(X[col])
    X[col] = (values.factorize()[0]+1).astype('float')

Y = (Y.factorize()[0]+1).astype('float')

Y = pd.DataFrame(Y, columns = ['FAILMODE'])

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.33)

X_train = X_train.as_matrix()
X_test = X_test.as_matrix()
Y_train = Y_train.as_matrix()
Y_test = Y_test.as_matrix()

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=7, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, nb_epoch=150, batch_size=10)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
print predictions[:20
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is this classification?

Comment: Yes. I've also done everything to change the training and test data `to_categorical` but I'm having problems with the shape of the data now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your model is wrong in this case, change it to:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(12, input_dim=7, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(7, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(122, init='uniform', activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

And make sure the input data is one-hot encoded with the function keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical. Then the model should train.

To then recover the integer class indices, when you predict with the model, you take the argmax of the output probability distribution, so you get the array index with the maximum probability.

```
x = some test point.
y = model.predict(x)[0]

class = np.argmax(y)
```